# REST Web Service: Server responding with a JAX-B error to GET

Tags: java, json, rest, netbeans, glassfish

I'm creating a RESTful Webservice with JAVA and netbeans. The Webservice outputs correct JSON data BUT the problem comes in when I want to read a variable I sent via GET when calling the webservice from the browser.

When I try to output the variable that I just sent with GET, the WS gives back a NULL.
In addition , Glassfish server console outputs this :

- INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class java.lang.String
- INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class java.lang.String
- ....
- INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class java.lang.String
- INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
- INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class java.lang.String

[image: Glassfish console]
[image: Coded Webservice]

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a @PathParam annotation you need to add the @Path annotation to the method declaration.

```
@GET
@Path("/{test}")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getJson(@PathParam("test") String test) {
    return test;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be the issue is because of CORS(Cross Origin ResourceSharing).Try to add CORS plugin for your browser or you can add CORS header in Response like return Response.ok(resp).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();